# import .vtk error in Python

Tags: python, import, vtk

I have Windows 8 64 bit and Python 2.11 64 bit. I install VTK library using pip command. It shows the following error while running:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import vtk
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vtk\__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    __helper.refine_import_err('rendering', 'vtkRenderingPython', exc)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vtk\__helper.py", line 32, in refine_import_err
    raise LinkError, str(exc)
LinkError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` Traceback
```

My PATH are:

```
C:\Python27\Lib;
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages;
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\vtk;
C:\Python27\Scripts;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: some library required a dll (build with source or globals). You install module anyway but can't build source of dll. you can't install module if haven't any C/C++ compiler(Not for all module). Check your PIP log you will be see more than one error.

Comment: Thank you. I could solve the problem with uninstalling .vtk and installing vtk 6.2. 0 from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem with uninstalling .vtk 5 and installing vtk 6.2. 0 from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. I also install PyQt4

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was resolved by adding PyQt4's directory to PATH, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501949/python-dll-import-error-when-importing-vtk#comment64411391_38501949). That is, the directory similar to

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4
```

which contains the DLL that it's looking for.