# Python DLL import error when importing vtk

Tags: python, windows, dll, pyqt, vtk

I need to use the *VTK* library (with version 5.10 because I am working on an existing code) in python on my Windows 10 machine but I can not manage to import it without `DLLImport` error:

```
Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import vtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vtk\__init__.py", line 139, in <module>
    __helper.refine_import_err('qvtk', 'vtkQtPython', exc)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vtk\__helper.py", line 32, in refine_import_err
    raise LinkError, str(exc)
vtk.__helper.LinkError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have installed *PyQt4* 4.11.4 and *VTK* 5.10.1 in 32 bits version (my Python 2.7.12 installation is 32 bits too), downloaded here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

I think the issue is related to the *vtkQtPython* pyd and dll (the files are `vtkQtPython.pyd` which tries to load `vtkQtPythonD.dll`:

```
>>> import qvtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "qvtk.py", line 5, in <module>
    from vtkQtPython import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>>> import vtkQtPython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Importing `vtk` using the latest version (7.0.0) does work, but is not compatible with the code I am working on. I have already tried uninstalling and set-up the whole installation again (all libraries and Python itself).

I hope you'll find some ideas, I still could not find any solution after hours struggling.

Comment: Run [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) on the suspected offending .pyd file to see if there are any missing .dll dependencies. I had similar issues when building vtk/mayavi. The solution was to add the bin directory from the vtk installation to the system PATH

Comment: According to it, there is a lot of missing dll files, [here is the log file](https://pastee.org/yt39b) (I could not host it on pastebin due to size limitation), I have no idea on how to resolve *all* these missing dependencies however. I have also tried adding the *vtk* python library (`C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\vtk`) to path, it did not change anything unfortunately.

Comment: You can ignore a lot of the Windows dependencies. It looks as though you're missing the Qt4 .dlls (in particular Qt4Core.dll and Qt4Gui.dll) and also msvcp90.dll, msvcr90.dll, which are part of the [msvc++ 2008 redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29)

Comment: I added the *PyQt4* directory (`C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4`to my PATH, it now properly works (it seems to work without the msvc++ 2008 redistributable though), thanks a lot!